# Matrix inverse series expansion

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse

I want to prove that when $I+K$ is invertible, $$(I+K)^{-1}=I-K+o(K)$$
to establish that the matrix inverse function has derivative $-I$ at $I$. My hope is that this identity carries over from $\mathbb{C}$, where we have $$(1+z)^{-1}=1-z+o(z)$$
and while we obviously have the expansion $(I-K)(I+K)=I-K^{2}=I+o(K)$, I'm not sure if this can be used to establish the above.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series is the phrase you are looking for.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the little-o notation. It does not make that much sense for a single matrix. Your proposition is indeed true for matrices of sufficiently small norm (namely $\Vert K\Vert_2\le\alpha<1$), but under this hypothesis the request of $I+K\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$ is superfluous.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Fair point, I've edited it to something hopefully more sensible. I did indeed mean that the matrix should have small norm - why does that make the invertibility condition superfluous?

Comment: Unless you mean the fact that the set of $K$ such that $I+K$ is invertible is dense in the set of $n\times n$ matrices (and hence the limit exists), is that it?

Comment: $I+K\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$ if and only if $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $K$, by Jordan's normal form theorem. Since $$\Vert A\Vert=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert Ax\Vert$$ is a norm, small matrices cannot have $-1$ as an eigenvalue. On the other hand, if $K$ has only big eigenvalues, then $I+K$ is invertible as well. In that case $K^2$ is not $o(K)$. That was part of my perplexities as well.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!